# Android Studio 3.5.2 androidx test became an unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-espresso, androidx, androidx-test

This morning, my android studio updated automatically.

And UI testing with espresso is broken.

The android jetpack test module became an unresolved reference now.

Do you have any solution for it?

```
13:11   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleMockDebugEmulator] in project /Users/hyung-jun.yoo/gitlab/app-banking-android

13:11   Gradle build finished in 4 s 910 ms

13:11   Install successfully finished in 6 s 829 ms.

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...

13:11   Emulator: Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/hyung-jun.yoo/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.

13:11   Emulator: Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...

13:11   Emulator: Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/Users/hyung-jun.yoo/.QtWebEngineProcess'

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/hyung-jun.yoo/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.

13:11   Emulator: Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/Users/hyung-jun.yoo/.QtWebEngineProcess'

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...

13:11   Emulator: Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...

13:11   Emulator: [1128/131156.257359:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale

13:11   Emulator: [1128/131156.257378:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
```

Comment: Please send us our logcat errors, we need to check the real problems.

Comment: Try Migrating to AndroidX and/or updating your libraries/Implementations to the latest versions